# Django-filter : working query is not working inside filtering method

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm building a filtering system with django-filters and I have a problem when using a custom filtering method. I have two models `Plat` and `UserAdvanced` which both have a `location` attribute corresponding to a Point from GeoDjango (it doesn't matter if you are not familiar with GeoDjango, the error is not GeoDjango related).

models.py

```
class UserAdvanced(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(blank = True, null = True)

class Plat(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(blank = True, null = True)
```

I want to filter all the `Plat` objects that are located at a distance less or equal than a value from the location of a `UserAdvanced` object. When I'm doing this in the shell, it works perfectly :

```
location2 = useradvanced_object.location
Plat.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(location2, D(m=1000)))
```

Note : `distance` is a build-in function of GeoDjango that can be applied to a point.

The problem is that, when I'm doing exactly the same thing inside a filtering method, I get an error. Here is the code :

filters.py

```
from actualites.models import Plat
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
import django_filters

class PlatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(PlatFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    distance_filter = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='location', method='distance_method'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Plat

    def distance_method(self, queryset, name, value):
        location2 = self.user.useradvanced.localisation
        return queryset.filter(location__distance_lte(location2, D(m = value)))
```

I get this error :

```
NameError at /
name 'location__distance_lte' is not defined
```

I've tried using name instead of location, using _ instead __, nothing works. I can't understand why since it works perfectly in the shell. I've verified that everything is well installed and imported in the virtual environment. A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Note : here are the local vars if it can help :

```
location2   <Point object at 0x7f06d91254d8>
name        'location'
queryset    <QuerySet [<Plat: PLAT TEST>, <Plat: Pâtes aux poivrons>, <Plat: Boeuf bourguingnon>, <Plat: Burrito mexicain>]>
self        <actualites.filters.PlatFilter object at 0x7f06d804e5f8>
value       Decimal('1000000000000')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on the distance_method

```
return queryset.filter(location__distance_lte(location2, D(m = value)))
```

must be:

```
return queryset.filter(location__distance_lte=(location2, D(m = value)))
                                            ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! No lies, it has been 4 days that I'm stuck with this, I've visited hundreds of topics, post lots of questions on forum, I can't believe it is so simple. Thanks again !